# Find out whole string inside square brackets and match one word inside square brackets using regex

Tags: regex, apex

I want to find out whole string and one word inside square bracket .

Sample string = `[This is my first Question]`;

I want to search it for `[This ..`

My expected output should be whole string inside bracket if string includes `[This`.

Can anyone help in this using regex? Any help would be appreciated.
My code is below :

```
string mainStr = 'wrapper s = [This is my first Question]'; 
Pattern pattr = Pattern.compile('\[This[^]]+\]'); 
Matcher mat = pattr .matcher(mainStr ); 
system.debug('mat is -----'+mat.matches());
system.debug('m is -----'+mat.find());
string n = null; 
if(mat.matches()) { n = mat.group(); system.debug('m is ----'+n); }
```

Comment: You will need to provide example strings and desired output for us to help you.

Comment: Try `\[This[^]]+\]` [here](https://regex101.com/r/BxMqB0/1)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness ....Thanks for quick response getting this  error .System.StringException: Invalid regex: Unmatched closing ')'

Comment: Share your code in the question.

Comment: My code is below : string mainStr = 'account s = [This is my first Question]'; 
      Pattern pattr = Pattern.compile('\\[This[^]]+\\]');
      Matcher mat = pattr .matcher(mainStr );     
      system.debug('mat is -----'+mat.matches()); 
      
      system.debug('m is -----'+mat.find());
      string n = null;
      if(mat.matches())
       {
         
         n = mat.group();
         system.debug('m is ----'+n);
       }

Comment: I have edited your question with your code. For next time, please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks @UnbearableLightness for editing ...

Answer (score 0):

if using regEx `(\[(\w+)[^]]+\])`

you get

- in $1 the string beetween [] and
- in $2 the first word inide of this.

Below you see a demo used inside a texteditor (phpStorm):

[image]

Comment: Thanks SL5net...but i want to match 'This' word in the string. And i have tried your regex in my code.but i did not get exact output.

Comment: so i recommand replacing `\w+v` with `This`. could you may give us your code?

Comment: ...Code is mentioned in question now.

Comment: .....I have tried your regex in my code but getting error .                  System.StringException: Invalid regex: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 5 (\[(\This)[^]]+\]) ^ ......................Please suggest.

Comment: Any suggestions on above question?